# Display inline two divs

Tags: html, css

I have this code HTML:

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
        <div class="site-branding">
            <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
            <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>



        </div><!-- .site-branding -->

        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
            <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="menu" aria-expanded="false"><?php _e( 'Primary Menu', 'eventos' ); ?></button>
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->

    </header><!-- #masthead -->
```

I want to arrange in line .site-branding and #site-navigation.

I tried to do this but not working

```
.site-branding,#site-navigation{display:inline-block;}
```

What is wrong in this code?

EDIT:

```
   .main-navigation {
    clear: both;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This is site:

http://eventos.dac-proiect.ro/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `#site-navigation` div element has a class `main-navigation` that may have some css rules overwriting the rule that you have described!

Comment: I put code for .main-navigation

Comment: In which browser you are testing it?

Comment: Can you please check my given solution once and let me know if still not working for you

Comment: I checked, I copied the code but still does not work

Comment: Apply my given css and remove width:100% from main-navigation class it will work for you

Comment: Still having same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are modifying a WordPress theme, which means there are other CSS rules that come into play.

It looks like you want `.site-branding` and `.main-navigation` to float to the left and remain within the parent block without breaking the rest of the layout.

I would apply `overflow: auto` to `.site-header` to create a block formatting context, which will keep the floated elements from interfering with any other elements in the layout.

Set the `width` of `.site-branding` to a small enough value to allow some space for the `.main-navigation`.  If you set it to 100%, the navigation will start on a second line.

I assume you want everything on a single line, otherwise, please clarify.

My example illustrates what you might be trying to do.  However, because you are working in WordPress with pre-existing style sheets, you need to make your CSS rules specific enough to style your header as needed without breaking other components such as WP's navigation panel and so on.

```css
.site-header {
  border: 1px dotted gray;
  overflow: auto;
}
.site-branding {
  border: 1px dotted gray;
  float: left;
  width: 50%; /* If value is 100%, .main-navigation will wrap to 2nd line */
}
.main-navigation {
  border: 1px dotted gray;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
  <div class="site-branding">
    <h1 class="site-title"><a href="#" rel="home">Site Title</a></h1>
    <h2 class="site-description">Description</h2>
  </div><!-- .site-branding -->

  <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
    <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="menu" aria-expanded="false">
      Primary Menu
    </button>
  </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
</header><!-- #masthead -->
```

Comment: but why when I put the code on my website not working?

Comment: On jsfiddle I saw you put the code works but only works on site

Comment: There may be other CSS rules that are affecting your elements.  When you say "not working", how is the layout behaving? You need to be more specific otherwise we are all guessing as to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Where do you want the navigation links to be, below the branding or to the right of the branding?  It looks like the width of the navigation is wider than 50%, so it wraps on to a second line.  You can try making the width of site branding smaller (25%?).

Comment: Right of the branding

Answer (score 0):

Please update css as given below

```
.site-branding,#site-navigation{display:inline-block; !important}
```

and remove `width:100%`from your main-navigation class.

But for better results always use `float:left` in css to do same things because inline-display I think will not work in IE7

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
.site-branding{
width:50%;
display:inline-block
}
```

and

```
.main-navigation {
    clear: both;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 49%;
    float: none;
}
```